# Error building BGFX on windows for mingw-gcc

Tags: c++, mingw, bgfx

I am trying to build bgfx on windows 64-bit with mingw-gcc and not Visual Studio. While trying to build I got errors

I tried to build the bgfx library with `make mingw-gcc-debug64` and I got errors while running the command. I got the following output: [command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHEzd.png) My gcc is installed at `C:\llvm-mingw\bin\gcc.exe`. Please let me know how I can fix this. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use msys2 to install MinGW and build from the mingw64 terminal.

Comment: Usage note: Don't post images of text. Not everyone can view images and many others simply won't risk clicking the link. Plus images can't be easily searched, making the question not useful to those who never find it. In general don't use an image as a primary source of information unless the question is about the image, as in you have a graphics programming problem, or you need to show something like a GUI configuration panel so we can see exactly what you have done.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, wont happen again :)

Comment: Ill try using the msys2 strategy @drescherjm

Comment: So I tried msys2 and it doesn't work, @drescherjm

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (note if your OS Linux you dont need install MSYS2- this is for Windows only)

0. install git, cmake.
1. Install  mingw64 via "MSYS2" devtools manager. this is manual how to do it https://www.devdungeon.com/content/install-gcc-compiler-windows-msys2-cc , install MSYS2 with all dev tools (gcc toollchanain, cmake, make, mc.. )
2. clone to your folder on your pc cmake-version of bgfx via command "git clone --recursive [https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx.cmake.git"](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx.cmake.git%22)
3. make build folder inside bgfx.cmake
4. from the build folder in command terminal type cmake "-G "MinGW Makefiles" .." (if your system is Linux just type "cmake .." )
5. "type cmake --build . --target examples" after type "cmake --build . --target tools"

That is all!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error. Building all the repos beforehand worked for me.

```bash
cd bx
make mingw-gcc-debug64

cd ..
cd bimg
make mingw-gcc-debug64

cd ..
cd bgfx
make mingw-gcc-debug64
```

I used [w64devkit](https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit/releases) (1.21.0).